# WASAPI IMMDevice underlying physical sound card

Tags: wasapi

I'm trying to pair together IMMDevice instances (input/output) that belong to the same physical sound card, f.i. "Line" input and "Speakers" output. How can I, given two IMMDevice instances, determine whether they derive from the same physical sound card? And no, ChatGPT didn't know :D

Comment: Asked the same question some time ago. There wasn't a definitive answer, but this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162130/how-to-enumerate-audio-cards-in-win32 might be a starting point.

Comment: @SjoerdvanKreel, thanks, the PKEY_Endpoint_Devnode property seems interesting!